# Base class for common YII functions?

Tags: yii

I know how to create a class the will allow me to instantiate it and use across my project. What I want to be able to do is have functions without instantiating classes. For example, I know how to do this:

```
$core = new core();
$val = $core->convertToMyNotation($anotherval);
```

But what I want is to be able to do this ANYWHERE in any view, class whatever:

```
$val = convertToMyNotation($anotherval);
```

Where would I place these functions in order to be able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

best way to do it, create a public function in components/Controller.php

```
public function globalFunction(){
 // do something here.
}
```

and access it anywhere by

```
$this->globalFunction();
```

Comment: This will work in controllers and view files, but not within any class that is not a controller, such as models.

Comment: in model can access as Yii::app()->getController()->globalFunction();

Comment: True, but this destroys some of the advantages of separating your code in MVC style, like Yii does. If someone uses your method in a console application, the default return value is NULL for the getController method, as controllers do not exist in console apps. If globalFunction() is only desired for use in a CWebApplication, then your solution is fine, but is not good as a general solution. In addition, you now have to think about where you are calling the globalFunction() method, and so call it differently depending on where you are.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a static method as an option.

```
class core{
    public static function convertToMyNotation($value){
        //do whatever here
        return $value;
    }
}
```

Then call it like so:

```
$val = core::convertToMyNotation($anotherval);
```

This requires no instantiation of the object to use. The only restriction is that you cannot use the `$this` property inside a static method.

Alternately, just define a file with your functions in it and include the file at some point early like, like within the boostrap script in your public_html/index.php file.

Edit: darkheir makes some good suggestions. Include such a class in your protected/components folder, and have it extend `CComponent` to gain some potentially useful enhancements.

By including the class in the protected/components folder, you gain the advantage of autoloading the class, by default.

Comment: and to call a static method from the same class since you can't use $this-> you'll have to use self::yourStaticFunction($value)

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive question of your answer, it depends a lot on what the function will be doing!

If the function is performing some things specific to a model
   (getting the last users, ...) this has to be in the User model as
   Willem Renzema described:

```
class theModelClass {
    public static function convertToMyNotation($value){
        //do whatever here
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And you'll call it like

```
$val = theModelClass::convertToMyNotation($anotherval);
```

If the function is handling user inputs (sanitizing he inputs,
   checking the values, ...) then it has to go to the controller and
   you'll use Hemc solution:

Create a public function in components/Controller.php

```
public function globalFunction(){
 // do something here.
}
```

and access it anywhere by

```
$this->globalFunction();
```

If the function is an Helper: performing some actions that do not
   depend on models or user inoput then you can create a new class that
   you'll put in your component directory:

```
class core extends CComponent{
    public static function convertToMyNotation($value){
        //do whatever here
        return $value;
    }
}
```

And

```
$val = core::convertToMyNotation($anotherval);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I think you're looking for this answer instead:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/31/use-shortcut-functions-to-reduce-typing/

In essence, in your entry script, before you load up Yii, include a global functions file:

```
require('path/to/globals.php');
```

Then, any function defined in that file can be used as a shortcut.  Be careful, but enjoy the power! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Create something like

```
Class Core extends CApplicationComponent{

    public function doSomething(){}
}
```

and in config main.php

```
'components'=>array(
    'core'=>array(
        'class' => 'Core'
    ),
),
```

and now you can call whenever you want

```
Yii::app()->core->doSomething();
```